# Simple sorting a table with help of C# (asp-net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question. I created a system where admin can add, edit or delete items (members of society in this case). I just need a sorting by year (top-bottom: from old to new) automatically without choices or buttons. I tried to run sorting with help of JavaScript, but it didn't work, unfortunately. It is sucessfully worked with data which was written with HTML, but, probably it doesn't work with data loaded from database which is my case. I read Microsoft tutorial, but didn't understand, honestly. Can you help me with automatic sorting by year? Thank You. All code is which downloads data from the database and shows it to the user is laid out below.

TeamController:

```
namespace Blog.Controllers {
    public class TeamController : Controller {
        private IRepository _repo;
        public TeamController(IRepository repo)
        { _repo = repo; }
        public IActionResult Index() {
            var team = _repo.GetAllPlayers();
            return View(team);
        }
    }    
}
```

Player.cs in Model

```
namespace Blog.Models
{
    public class Player {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string NickName { get; set; } = "";
        public string Position { get; set; } = "";
        public string MemberSince { get; set; } = "";
        public string Category { get; set; } = "";
    }
}
```

index.cshtml (Team)

```
@model IEnumerable<Player>
<div>
    <table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">NickName</th>
                <th scope="col">Position</th>
                <th scope="col">Member since</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var player in Model) {
                @if (@player.Category == "Owner") {
                    <tr asp-controller="Team" asp-action="Player" asp-route-id="@player.Id">
                        <td data-label="NickName" id="nickname"> @player.NickName</td>
                        <td data-label="Position">@player.Position</td>
                        <td data-label="MemberSince">@player.MemberSince</td>
                    </tr>
                 }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Repository.cs

```
public Player GetPlayer(int id)
        { return _ctx.Team.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id); }
public List<Player> GetAllPlayers()
        { return _ctx.Team.ToList(); }
```

IRepository.cs

```
Player GetPlayer(int id);
List<Player> GetAllPlayers();
```

Comment: If i'm understanding your question, you can use a LINQ query before you return the result of `GetAllPlayers()` such as `return _ctx.Team.OrderBy(player => player.MemberSince).toList();`

Comment: Have you tried using OrderBy? Also, which field are you trying to sort? Is it `MemberSince`? If so, you can do `.OrderBy(member => DateTime.Parse(member.MemberSince)` to soet on datetime instead of string sort

Comment: @Joe `OrderBy` should be before `ToList()` because every operation after `ToList()` is done in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Use orderby along with DateTime parsing.

```
public List<Player> GetAllPlayers()
        { return _ctx.Team.OrderBy(member => DateTime.Parse(member.MemberSince).Year).ToList(); }
```

You can use OrderByDesc if you want latest first.